# check if a directory exists using FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm using FTPClient (org.​apache.​commons.​net.​ftp.​FTPClient) to upload some files to a FTP server.
I need to check if parent directories exists or not; and create them if needed.
How can I check file/directory existence using FTPClient?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the FTP STAT command.

You can use this [API call](https://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getStatus%28java.lang.String%29) to check what you're after.

Comment: Hi , Thanks; can you explain more? this returns `213-STAT
 213 End.` ! How should I understand directory exists from this?

Comment: Unfortunately STAT and LIST provide the same result.  I guess if you get a zero length list of information ... and you'll have to pardon the fact that it's been YEARS since I had gotten this low level in FTP protocol ... STAT and LIST if used on an existing directory should at least provide '.' and '..' as directories available on a valid directory.

Comment: API call is FTPClient.getStatus(java.lang.String) - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getStatus(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
public static boolean isExists(FTPClient ftpClient, String pathName)
{
    ftpClient.getStatus(pathName);
    return FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it worked for me.:

```
FTPClient ftpClient=null;
        (ftpClient = new FTPClient()).connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");           

        if(ftpClient.login("user", "pass")){            
            System.out.println(ftpClient.cwd("folder/subfolder"));    
***// if returns 250, folder exists  and if returned 550 folder does not exist***       

        }
```